# Command needed to change value to integer

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have one file in which we have data like this:

```
CC,1234,Piyush,0.0,
```

Whenever `0.0` comes in file it should replace by `0` only.
How do I replace without using `sed` command to replace all in file.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Question is not asking to round numbers, it's just replacement of `0.0` with `0`.

Comment: Piyush Kapoor: Although it seems to me (and @αғsнιη) that you *just* want `0.0` changed to `0` and nothing else done--and I *don't* think we should consider this question unclear--I think it would be best if you **[edit]** to clarify if `0.0` is the only thing you want changed. For example, if `1.0` appears, should that be changed to just `1`? If so, what of `1.1`--should it be rounded down to `1`? (And if so what about `2.5`--should that be rounded [down to `2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) or [up to `3`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_up)?)

Comment: Why not `sed`? Are other command-line text processing tools allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `sed`?

```
sed 's/\<0\.0\>/0/g' infile
```

Then use `awk`.

```
awk '{gsub(/\<0\.0\>/,"0")}1' infile
```

Comment: If it's a number like 3.7, it'll cut off .7, loss of significant digit values. Use printf in awk to at least round properly

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy it's not cutting.

Comment: Yeah, because your pattern only looks for 0.0, you're not considering that OP's data can be varied. It's a hard coded solution that'll work only in one specific case.  I'm giving you suggestion on improving the answer, that's all.

Comment: Still not clear for me you are pointing on what hardcode, that's what OP want only `0.0` and I'm preventing replace numbers line `1230.012` or `0.0123` as if I do, the numbers completely will being change!

Answer (score 0):

In case you only want to replace column values that hold the exact string `0.0`, here's an Awk program that takes care of column management:

```sh
awk -F , 'BEGIN{ OFS=FS; } { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i=="0.0") $i="0"; print; }' input.csv > output.csv
```